# How would I Add Two "AD" Groups in 1 LDAP Server

Tags: authentication, svn, active-directory, ldap, authorization

I have installed and configured a `subversion` in `Linux7` and from the front end I am using `svn tortoise`. From server lever, I want to integrate my `subversion` with `AD`.

I have two repositories inside `/u01/ciroot/subversion`, like `DEV_REPO` and `PROD_REPO`.

Also in `AD` I have two groups; one is `OBIEE_DEV` and another is `OBIEE_PROD`. Now I want members of group `OBIEE_DEV` to access the repository `DEV_REPO` and members of group `OBIEE_PROD`
to access the repository `DEV_REPO` and `PROD_REPO` (both). So in my `AD`, under group `OBIEE_DEV`, I have `user1` and `user2` both there, but in the `AD` group `OBIEE_PROD` I only have `user2`.

These things are placed properly. But in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` file how should I declare this? Below is my subversion.conf file where right now only one group entry is mentioned which is OBIEE_DEV, i want to add entry for group OBIEE_PROD too here. Please guide me how to achieve this.

```
<pre>
    <location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /u01/ciroot/subversion
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthName "Root Repo"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.server.com:389/DC=macgroup,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(ObjectClass=*)(memberOf=CN=OBIEE_DEV,OU=OBIEE,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=Global Resources,DC=MACGROUP,DC=LOCAL))" STARTTLS

        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=oidkerbt,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Global 
        Resources,DC=macgroup,DC=local"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword password_of_ldap_server
        Require valid-user
    </location>
</pre>
```

Comment: I'd say you have to instead create two distinct `<location>` entries — matching the pathnames of your logical repos under `/u01/ciroot/subversion`

Comment: JFTR there's not such thing as "Linux7". Linux is [an operating system _kernel_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), not an OS. Judging from the number 7, you might have wanted to refer to CentOS or RHEL, but I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

First, read the box titled "Do You Really Need Path-Based Access Control?" here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

But if you still decide you want to do this, that link should help you set this up. But basically, create two `location` entries: one for each repository. You point each at the group at the AD group that grants that permission.

If you want people in the `OBIEE_PROD` group to have access to the `DEV_REPO` too, then just add the `OBIEE_PROD` group to your `OBIEE_DEV` group in AD.

This is an example, but I can't guarantee this will work exactly as-is:

```
<location /svn/DEV_REPO>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /u01/ciroot/subversion
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "Root Repo"
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.server.com:389/DC=macgroup,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(ObjectClass=*)(memberOf=CN=OBIEE_DEV,OU=OBIEE,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=Global Resources,DC=MACGROUP,DC=LOCAL))" STARTTLS

    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=oidkerbt,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Global 
    Resources,DC=macgroup,DC=local"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword password_of_ldap_server
    Require valid-user
</location>
<location /svn/PROD_REPO>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /u01/ciroot/subversion
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "Root Repo"
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.server.com:389/DC=macgroup,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(ObjectClass=*)(memberOf=CN=OBIEE_PROD,OU=OBIEE,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=Global Resources,DC=MACGROUP,DC=LOCAL))" STARTTLS

    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=oidkerbt,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Global 
    Resources,DC=macgroup,DC=local"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword password_of_ldap_server
    Require valid-user
</location>
```

Comment: ....i want to say thank you for suggesting this. Yes i had tried this and it worked with me with SVNPath. When i was giving SVNParentPath and giving the path of my parent SVN location, it was not working, so instead to SVNParentPath, i gave SVNPath and give location till my repository like /u01/ciroot/subversion/DEV_REPO. I want to say thank you to you for guiding me on this. Regards

Comment: Glad I could help.